# Many To Many relationships in Laravel: belongsToMany() vs. hasManyThrough()

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

What is the difference between using belongsToMany() or hasManyThrough() when defining a Many To Many relationship in Laravel?

Example:
`User`
`Account`
`Account_User`

So, User has a many to many relation to Account via the Account_User table. On top of being just the pivot table that defines the related Users with related Accounts, it also stores a `Account_User.role` field, which determines which role a given user has in a given account.

What would the implications be of using either `User belongsToMany() Account` or `User hasManyThrough() Account Account_User`? Or is this essentially the same?

When decided upon a method, I guess I should use the same method for the reverse relation definition.

Comment: Has many through is not proper for your approach. Negatively, you will have to add a Eloquent model for the pivot table. As I've stated in my answer, they are different things, and for your example has many through is not suitable. Think Account_user is a part of account and user tables, not like a third table.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's say you have two models, let's call `A` and `B`:

If `A` may have more than one items of `B`, 
and also
If `B` may have more than one items of `A`
(think like blog posts / tags)
You have to use `belongsToMany()`;

Now let's say you have 3 models, `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` is related to `B`, and `B` is related to `C`. But you need to access all `C`'s which is related to `A` (over `B`), then you need to use `hasManyThrough()`
(think like `countries` -> `users` -> `posts` , and you need all `post`s from specific `country`)

`hasManyThrough()` is not totally meant for many to many relationships, it's more like a shortcut.

Check the documentation links, [1](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many), [2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through) (Laravel 4.2), or [3](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), [4](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) (Laravel 5.x).

Comment: I understand, so I updated the question to ne more specific. I simply don't really get what the pros/cons for the two approaches are - or if there is a difference at all.

Comment: There really aren't pros and cons because they are both doing different things.  `belongsToMany()` usually includes a pivot table, `hasManyThrough()` is just a shortcut for `hasMany` so instead of having `countries->users->posts`, if you setup a `hasManyThrough()` relationship, all you need to do is `countries->posts`;

Answer (score 11):

While @Arda's answer is absolutely correct, I found myself needing some time to digest it. So here is my attempt to put the same thing in simpler terms.

`hasManyThrough` is useful when you have something similar to the following scenario:

- A company has many offices and each office has many employees working in it. In other words, `Company` one-to-many `Office`, and `Office` one-to-many `Employee`. And if you want to fetch all employees working for a given company, you need:

```
// Company Model

public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Employee', 'App\Office');
}
```

`belongsToMany`, on the other hand, is useful when you have a many-to-many relationship with a pivot table in-between. For example:

- A film can have many categories (comedy, drama, etc.) and each category can belong to many films. In other words, `Film` many-to-many `Category`. And if you want to fetch all categories for a given film, you need:

```
// Film Model

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'pivot_table_name');
}
```

Given the scenario in question, `belongsToMany` is the relationship needed to connect many `Users` to many `Accounts`. `hasManyThrough` cannot be applied.